# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php

I am connected to my server as a root user I have a simple php script:

```
<?php
$url ="http://www.ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl";
fopen($url, 'r');
?>
```

once I run this `php5 script.php` I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(http://www.ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl): 
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
```

Notice that when I try another url exp: http://google.com the script shows no warnings or errors, also when I type the required url into my browser it works.
I checked my php.ini and the variable `allow_url_fopen` is already set to `On`.
from another server I tried the same script (the same url)and it works so the problem is related with my server not with the required service.
Any idea how to avoid this?

### edit:

$url = "http://www.ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl";

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

gives:

```
* About to connect() to ec.europa.eu port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 2001:bc8:3408:200::2... * connected
> GET /taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: ec.europa.eu
Accept: */*

* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 310
< 
* Excess found in a non pipelined read: excess = 20, size = 310, maxdownload = 310, bytecount = 0
* Closing connection #0
string(310) "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Erreur 503</h1>
<h2>Erreur proxy ipv6</"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple curl request

```
$url = "http://www.ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Returns a "Access Denied Your request has been denied for security reason" are you sure you're not blocking requests on your end?